# Can you cast MaterialTextField as an Entry?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have successfully followed the [instructions](https://mikalaidaronin.info/blog/posts/xamarin-forms-password-autofill/) to implement a  *Password AutoFill* effect on Xamarin.Forms Entry elements - this is behaving properly on both Android and iOS platforms. However, I am unable to get the effect to work when I use it on the MaterialTextField element from the [XF.Material](https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library) library.

I believe that the issue comes down to the native effect implementation for both iOS and Android, where I cast the xamarin form elements to native platform elements; in Android I need to use an EditText element, while in iOS I need to use a UITextField element. I haven't been able to cast the *MaterialTextField* to either of these elements.

Is this even possible using the XF.Material library element like this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you to everyone in this community!

Comment: Add your code so people can understand what you are trying to point

Comment: @FreakyAli You can have a try with [Xamarin.Forms Material Visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) .Xamarin.Forms Material Visual can be used to apply Material Design rules to Xamarin.Forms applications, creating applications that look largely identical on iOS and Android. When Material Visual is enabled, supported views adopt the same design cross-platform, creating a unified look and feel.

Comment: you should install Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponent and use TextField instead of UITextField.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I know what Material visual is I was just asking him to add his code as that would help us.

Comment: @FreakyAli Yeah , that will be helpful .